# Manually calculate the variance-covariance matrix for a fitted GLS model -- i.e., vcov(glsModel)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares

I've been working to better understand GLS by manually fitting the parameters in R. In the example below I fit the coefs of a GLS from the `nlme` package in R. However, I'm trying now to calculate the standard errors on those coefs. I don't understand how the variance-covariance matrix for a fitted GLS model is calculated (i.e., `vcov(glsModel)` in R).

```
library(nlme)
set.seed(3415)
n <- 25
x <- rnorm(n = n)
B0 <- 10
B1 <- 0.5
phi <- 0.8
epsilon <- arima.sim(model = list(c(1,0,0), ar = phi),n=n, sd=0.5)
y <- B0 + B1 * x + epsilon

# Fit a gls with ar1 errors fixed to phi so I can 
# compare results easily...
gls1 <- gls(y~x,correlation = corAR1(value = phi,fixed=TRUE))
coef(gls1)

############################
# Fit the GLS model
############################
# 1. Create design matrix
X <- cbind(1, x)
# equivalent to model.matrix(gls1)
# 2. Get the variance-covariance matrix of errors
V <- toeplitz(phi^(1:n-1)) * 0.5^2
# 3. Fit GLS model using matrix algebra
Sigma <- solve(V)
XtX <- t(X) %*% Sigma %*% X
Xty <- t(X) %*% Sigma %*% y
betas <- solve(XtX) %*% Xty
betas # equivalent to coef(gls1)

############################
## Get std errors
############################

# 1. Get residuals
e <- as.matrix(y-betas[1] - betas[2]*x)
e # equivalent to resid(gls1)

# 2. calc variance-cov mat for the fitted model -- aka vcov(gls1)
vcov(gls1) #??
```

I've tried several approaches to getting `vcov(gls1)` manually but I'm flailing about. Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an attempt to match your variable names, suppose the (conditional) error covariance matrix $\Psi = \sigma^2 \Sigma^{-1} = \sigma^2V$ in your general linear regression model is know up to a positive constant $\sigma^2$. Then, the (conditional) covariance matrix of the generalized least squares estimator $\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}$ is given by
$$
\mathop{\mathbb{V}}\left(\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}\,|\,X\right) = \left(X^\top \Psi^{-1} X\right)^{-1} = \sigma^2\left(X^\top \Sigma X\right)^{-1}.
$$
To obtain an unbiased estimator of $\mathop{\mathbb{V}}\left(\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}\,|\,X\right)$ we thus need an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$. One such estimator$-$the one that will answer your question$-$is given by
$$
\hat\sigma^2= \frac{1}{n-k} \left(y - X\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}\right)^\top \Sigma\left(y - X\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}\right),
$$
where $n$ is the number of entries of $y$ and $k$ the number of entries of $\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}$.

In your example we have
$$
\Psi
= \sigma^2 \frac{1}{1-\phi^2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \phi & \cdots & \phi^{n-1} \\
\phi & 1 & & \phi^{n-2} \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
\phi^{n-1} & \phi^{n-2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= \sigma^2 V,
$$
where $\sigma^2 = 0.5^2$ is the variance of the innovations $u_t$ in your AR(1) error term process $\varepsilon_t = \phi\varepsilon_{t-1} + u_t$, $u_t \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ with AR coefficient $\phi = 0.8$.

In your code this would correspond to redefining

```r
V <- toeplitz(phi^(1:n - 1)) / (1 - phi^2)
```

which doesn't change `betas` (the realized value of $\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}$) since any scaling factor of $V$ cancels out in the corresponding calculation.
With the new `V` (and thus new `Sigma`) you can calculate the realization of $\hat \sigma^2$ via

```r
sigma_sq_hat <- as.numeric(1/(n-2) * t(e) %*% Sigma %*% e)
```

and the realized value of $\mathop{\hat{\mathbb{V}}}\left(\hat\beta_{\text{GLS}}\,|\,X\right) = \hat \sigma^2 \left(X^\top \Sigma X\right)^{-1}$, i.e. `vcov(gls1)`, via

```r
sigma_sq_hat * solve(XtX)
```

Note that, again due to cancellation, this term would be the same if calculated with your original definition of `V`; but `sigma_sq_hat` would then be scaled by a factor of $100/9$.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thanks for such a detailed reply. Much clearer now.

Comment: @user111024 I'm glad I could help.